# Model Fit Keras

Tags: keras

I am having some trouble to understand some arguments of `model.fit` function in Keras.

[Model Keras](https://keras.io/models/model/)

In my problem i have a total of 1147 samples, and i have split those samples for training and validation (80% for training and 20% for validation). I am using the same batch size for training and validation. So, i got this:

```
Total_Samples = 1147
Training_Samples = 918
Validation_Samples = 229
Batch_Size = 16 # For Training and Validation
```

**1st Question:** Is the `steps_per_epoch = Total_Samples/Batch_Size`?

**2nd Question** Is the `validation_steps = Validation_Samples/Batch_Size`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `steps_per_epoch` will be `Training_Samples` (not `Total_Samples`) divided by `Batch_Size`. Similarly, the `validation_steps` will be `Validation_Samples` divided by `Batch_Size`.